# Is there a way to initialize a Vue object preserving initial HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mvvm, vue.js

I want to use Vue.js to more easily manipulate the DOM but when I initialize a Vue object it rewrites initial data that is generated with backend at first before manipulating.

For example I have this markup:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li v-repeat="elements" v-text="content">a</li>
  <li v-repeat="elements" v-text="content">b</li>
  <li v-repeat="elements" v-text="content">c</li>
</ul>
```

And then I want to use `new Vue({ el: '#list' })` so that it would somehow read already existing markup and preserve it before manipulating via editing `$data`. Is this somehow achievable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not possible the way you want to do it. Vue.JS doesn't operate on the DOM directly. It reads the DOM elements, converts them into a render function and replaces the whole Element with the result of the render-function.

You should probably use JQuery to scan your DOM and fill your $data object (and possibly your template-string for Vue) and then initialie your Vue instance with this generated data.

But overall - you should rethink your application logic, because you seem to be doing something very convoluted, which could possibly be solved a lot easier. Whatever generates your DOM-Template could probably also directly render into a JS-variable, or even be accessed with an AJAX call...

If you want to render a fallback approach if the client does not support JS or the CDN for Vue is not available you can use the script-template approach. Define your Vue.JS content in a script-tag, which will replace the original DOM, when Vue is ready.

Example:

```js
function loadVue() {
  new Vue({
    data: { values: [ 'aaa','bbb','ccc' ] },
    template: '#list-template',
    el: '#list'
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <button onclick="loadVue()">Load Vue.JS</button>
</ul>

<script type="text/x-template" id="list-template">
<ul id="list">
  <li v-for="v in values">{{v}}</li>
</ul>
</script>
```

Comment: I was just thinking if I could actually keep it unobtrusive. Say js is disabled but then I still have a list pre-initialized.

Comment: @German I've added an example how to solve the alternate content without JS/Vue Problem you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't use a combination of already existing elements and a `v-repeat` like this

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#list',
    data: {
        elements: [{
            content: "d (v-repeat)"
        }, {
            content: "e (v-repeat)"
        }, {
            content: "f (v-repeat)"
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.11.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li v-repeat="elements" v-text="content">c</li>
</ul>
```

You just don't put a `v-repeat` on the elements that are already present.

Comment: But that way a, b and c aren't accessable via the Vue. I can't delete them or change their contents. The task was to preload initial data, not just to have additional unaffected tags.